# TSQL - Update table from itself

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Table **Item** (4 columns, simplified for the sake of clarity)

```
Record | Item | Price | Zone
```

**Data**

```
1      | 100  | 10.00 | A
2      | 100  | NULL  | B
3      | 100  | NULL  | C
4      | 200  | 25.00 | A
5      | 200  | NULL  | B
```

Trying to update the `NULL`s with the corresponding values from the non-`NULL`s based on `Item`. So all Item 100s would read 10.00 and both Item 200s would read 25.00.

I feel like this should be super easy, but can't figure out the self reference.

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: njk - Point taken and understood. I didn't have anything that I thought was close, so I kept it out. I'll make it more detailed in the future. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

here u go

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Price=b.Price
FROM  Item AS a
INNER JOIN Item AS b
ON a.item=b.item
WHERE a.Price is NULL AND b.price is NOT NULL
```

or if there are multiple Non-null prices and you want to choose maximum price.

```
 UPDATE a
 SET a.Price=(SELECT MAX(b.PRICE) FROM ITEM AS b WHERE b.Item=a.Item and b.Price is not null )
 FROM  Item AS a
 WHERE a.Price is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have multiple prices for an item, one needs to be selected. This sample picks the minimum one (it is a bit confusing with the column name `item` being the same as the table name):

```
UPDATE item i
  SET price = (SELECT MIN(price)
                FROM item
                WHERE item = i.item
                GROUP BY item)
```

Comment: Agreed on the confusing naming convention in my example. Those were quick names I used in lieu of the actual names, field235, field9494, etc. Thanks for the response.